# How do I find the script used in this webpage to calculate calories burned based on the form values?

Tags: javascript

This website: [https://healthstatus.com/calculate/cbc](https://www.healthstatus.com/calculate/cbc) has a bunch of fields in a form that calculate the # of calories burned based on gender, age, height, and weight.

I'd like to analyze this but am having trouble finding the script that does all the math. The `form` in inspect shows the link that returns the results, but I can't find anything in the console that has any kind of math or weighting to calculate the calories burned. Any help?

Here's the `form` line, but that link only goes to the results:

```
<form method="POST" action="/perl/calculator.cgi" class="form-horizontal" id="calc">
```

Each form value has this structure:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xs-12 c_form_left">Brush teeth</div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xs-12 c_form_right">
        <input type="number" id="imperial_T107" name="T107" value="" min="1" class="c_input" max="1440"/>
            </div><div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Looks like the script is on the server /perl/calculator.cgi. So you won't be able to "download" it like a js file.

Comment: @chickenchilli I'm assuming that also means I am unable to view it at all?

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: @chickenchilli is correct. There is no way to view the source of a script that is executing server-side without having access to said server.